# Create multiple condition value counts table in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Pandas (yet I have read dozens of threads looking for answers).

What I am trying to do is to convert a table that goes as:

col1 (names), col2(products) in order to see which seller was selling what products in what percentage (out of his own volume).

Initial dataframe looks like

```
John "Product A"
John "Product A"
Jack "Product B"
James "Product C"
```

And so forth.

What I need to get is a table of

```
     Prod A Prod B Prod C
John   %      %       %
Jack
James
```

In Excel I would do it with countifs/sumifs functions and would easily create a table.

Basically, I have managed to achieve my goal, but the way I did it is horrendous:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"filename")

data4 = data[['name', 'product']]

vc =  data4['name'].value_counts(0)
type(vc)
vc.values
vc.index.values
counts_frame = pd.DataFrame({'values':vc.index, 'count':vc.values})
counts_frame

A_counts = data4[data4['product']=="Продукт А"]['name'].value_counts(0)
a = A_counts.to_frame()
B_counts = data4[data4['product']=="Продукт В"]['name'].value_counts(0)
b = B_counts.to_frame()
C_counts = data4[data4['product']=="Продукт С"]['name'].value_counts(0)
c = C_counts.to_frame()

proda = counts_frame.merge(a, how='left', left_on=['values'], right_on=a.index)
prodb = proda.merge(b, how='left', left_on=['values'], right_on=b.index)
prodc = prodb.merge(c, how='left', left_on=['values'], right_on=c.index)
prodc
```

The image of a table I want to get is attached. I am sure Pandas has a way to do it with less code and without manually inserting column names.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL9zi.png)

Comment: It solved it for me:

group = data4.groupby(['name', 'product'])
new_table = group.count()
new_table.reset_index(inplace=True) 
new_table.pivot(index='name', columns='product', values='nan')

I had to add a random column as 'nan'.

It can be put even simpler:

pd.crosstab(data4['name'], data4['product'])

Comment: You can add it as an answer instead of a comment.